# Bind to key release without repeat

Tags: autohotkey, key-bindings

```
SC039::Send {LShift down}

SC039 Up::
Send, {LShift up}
Send, {Space}
Return
```

I expect this to do the following: when pressing the spacebar, it acts like the shift key. When I release it, I get one space bar press. Unfortunately, when I stay on the space bar, I get a bunch of spaces even though the key is never released. How can this expected behavior be implemented?

Comment: Is that for a game? If so I'd ask in [this forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=18&sid=3afbfd16e018c0f439e6ee55a57e951c).

Comment: @user3419297 I would but they aren't sending me the confirmation mail ^^. If you're curious what I'm doing: I want to double bind my space bar as I am used to having a shorter one with a shift key on the left of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `*` modifier<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)</sup> so the hotkey is recongnized even if extra modifiers are held down (<kbd>Shift</kbd>)
Also, why are you using using the scancode?

```
*Space::SendInput, {LShift Down}
*Space Up::SendInput, {LShift Up}{Space}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. I don't have a good reason for the scan codes, I was just tinkering around in Linux before this where I needed to use them. If they are equivalent to the names, then I will use those.

Comment: Actually one qustion: how do I preserve the modifiers when sending the Space? Since with the star it accepts all modifiers but then erases them

Comment: You want the [blind mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind) to preserve modifiers.

Comment: Answer: markall `send`s as blind

Answer (score 0):

Check dual-key "SpaceFN" keyboard layout https://github.com/lydell/spacefn-win

Probably this is what you are looking for or even more.